# Обработка нажатий переключателя

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть 5 переключателей надо чтобы при смене их позиций вкл/выкл менялся цвет текста рядом с ними.Цвет текста не важен.

Пример:

```css
/* Вторая кнопка */

.cmn-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  top: 495px;
  left: 575px;
  z-index: 8;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #161616;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round+label:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #4cda64;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 21px;
}


/* Третья кнопка */

.cmn-toggle1 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle1+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  top: 555px;
  left: 575px;
  z-index: 9;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round1+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round1+label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round1+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-round1+label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #161616;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round1+label:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round1:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #4cda64;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round1:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 21px;
}


/* Первая кнопка */

.cmn-toggle2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle2+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  top: 337px;
  left: 575px;
  z-index: 7;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round2+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round2+label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round2+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-round2+label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #161616;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round2+label:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round2:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #4cda64;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round2:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 21px;
}


/* Четвертая кнопка */

.cmn-toggle3 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle3+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  top: 576px;
  left: 575px;
  z-index: 7;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round3+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round3+label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round3+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-round3+label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #161616;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round3+label:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round3:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #4cda64;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round3:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 21px;
}


/* Пятая кнопка */

.cmn-toggle4 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -9999px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cmn-toggle4+label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  user-select: none;
  top: 637px;
  left: 575px;
  z-index: 9;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round4+label {
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  border-radius: 60px;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round4+label:before,
input.cmn-toggle-round4+label:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
}

input.cmn-toggle-round4+label:before {
  right: 1px;
  background-color: #161616;
  border-radius: 60px;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round4+label:after {
  width: 30px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round4:checked+label:before {
  background-color: #4cda64;
}

input.cmn-toggle-round4:checked+label:after {
  margin-left: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-1"></label>
  <p>текст</p>
</div>

<div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-2" class="cmn-toggle1 cmn-toggle-round1" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-2"></label>
  <p>текст</p>
</div>

<div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-3" class="cmn-toggle2 cmn-toggle-round2" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-3"></label>
  <p>текст</p>
</div>

<div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-4" class="cmn-toggle3 cmn-toggle-round3" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-4"></label>
  <p>текст</p>
</div>

<div class="switch">
  <input id="cmn-toggle-5" class="cmn-toggle4 cmn-toggle-round4" type="checkbox">
  <label for="cmn-toggle-5"></label>
  <p>текст</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поднимаемся от чекбокса вверх до ближайшего родителя с классом `"switch"`, в котором находим элемент `<p>`:

```
$(".switch input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
  $(this).closest(".switch").find("p").
    css("color", this.checked? "green" : "black");
});
```